# Python 3 Error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.89*10**-5' ?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a code like the given below:

```
p=float(input('enter the particle density(g/cm3):'))
g=9.81#gravitation acceleration
pw=1           
dp=float(input('enter the diameter of particle in mm:'))
m=float(input('enter the viscocity of the fluid:'))
Vs=(g*(p-pw)*(dp*10**-3)**2)/(18*m)        
print("the settling velocity of the particle is"+str(Vs))
```

It takes input from the terminal as follows:

```
[Desktop]$ python3 settling_velocity.py 

enter the particle density(g/cm3):2
enter the diameter of the particle in mm:2
enter the viscosity of the fluid:0.89*10**-5
```

And produces some result with python2.7, but when I run this code with python3 it shows error like

```
Python 3 Error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.89*10**-5' ?
```

How can I solve this, please help..

thanks

Comment: Try to input `0.89*10**-5` as `0.89e-5`

Comment: `input` is different in the 2 versions.  One evaluates the string, the other just returns the string, leaving you to evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `input()` evaluates the response as an expression. Python 3 did away with this, and just returns a string.

You should use [exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) to type a float with a power of 10 multiplier:

```
enter the viscosity of the fluid:0.89E-5
```

Comment: The number after the `E` is a power of 10, not of 2.

Comment: Don't know how that happened, I was definitely thinking 10 when I typed it.